# How to loop through an array and display each value next to eachother with a 500ms interval using pureJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, intervals

The loop below basically loops through my array which is `sumFormat` then displays each value of the array with a `500ms` interval, which is fine, but its displaying the array values only once at time so

for example if the array contains `[1, 2, 3]`

- it displays `1` then `500ms` later displays `2` in place of the `1`,
- but I want it to display `1` then `500ms` later display `2` next to
- the `1` so `1 2`
- and then `1 2 3` and so on,

I've tried to figure it out but can't seem to get it right.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sumFormat.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            factOut.innerHTML = sumFormat[i];
        }, 500 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Side note, why  `500 * i` would this increase the internal as `i` increases.

Comment: @Seabizkit. It's because all setTimeouts are created at once.  So another side note this is very sub optimal, things like timers are a limited resourse.

Comment: @Keith so should I remove the `* i` part?

Comment: @Keith yeah i get they created once but its still odd.. wouldn't this be better   
`const sumFormat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var index =0;
setInterval(myMethod, 500);
function myMethod( )
{
 if(index >= sumFormat.length)
 {
  index =0;
 }
 factOut.textContent += ' ' + sumFormat[index];
 
  index = index + 1;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate with the existing `innerHTML` instead of just assigning to it, since that will overwrite whatever was there previously. You can also use `let` instead of `var` to make the code much neater. Also, since you're only inserting *text*, not HTML markup, better to use `textContent` instead:

```js
const sumFormat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < sumFormat.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    factOut.textContent += ' ' + sumFormat[i];
  }, 500 * i);
}
```

```html
<div id="factOut"></div>
```

Another method, by joining the array items from 0 to the current index:

```js
const sumFormat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < sumFormat.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    factOut.textContent = sumFormat.slice(0, i + 1).join(' ');
  }, 500 * i);
}
```

```html
<div id="factOut"></div>
```

Comment: Also instead of ```factOut.innerHTML```, you can replace ```factOut.textContent```  as the value is just text and not ```HTML``` element..

Comment: use of `slice()`  I liked it (Y)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things I would change here.

Using multiple setTimeout's and setting the timeout's as increasing values could cause you issues if you wanted lots of them, timeout's are a limited resource in JS.

One option is possibly using setInterval as someone here as shown, but my favourite is using async / await.

Also if your list got very long, constantly changing the innerHTML would not be very kind to the DOM, instead creating another DOM element and adding those would be more efficient.  Another advantage of them been separate is it make's it much simpler to style them too.

Below is an example using `async/await` and adding to the DOM, instead of constantly updating the innerHTML, and for fun just putting a bit of style to it.

```js
const delay=ms=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,ms));

(async function() {
  const sumFormat = [1,2,3,4];
  for (const i of sumFormat) {
    const num = document.createElement('span');
    num.innerText = i;
    factOut.appendChild(num);
    await delay(500);
  }
}());
```

```css
span {
  padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
  margin: 0.2rem 0.3em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="factOut"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Example with `setInterval()`

```js
function SetValue(text, at){
     factOut.innerHTML += text[at] + (text.length-1 == at ?"":" "); 
} 

var sumFormat = [1,2,3,4,5];
var i = 0;
var myinterval = setInterval(function(){
     if(i == sumFormat.length){
      clearInterval(myinterval);
      return;
     }
     SetValue(sumFormat,i);
     i++;
},500)
```

```html
<div id="factOut" />
```